# Calling Watson on Bluemix from java causes Trust Manager error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Trying out some code to call a Watson Service I provisioned on Bluemix. I get the following error:

> Unable to extract the trust manager on
>   okhttp3.internal.Platform@e19ef72e, sslSocketFactory is class
>   com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl

Here is my code:

```
try {
    DocumentConversion service = new DocumentConversion("2016-05-25");
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("*****", "*****");

    File doc = new File("C:/Sample1.pdf");
    Answers htmlToAnswers =   service.convertDocumentToAnswer(doc).execute();
    System.out.println(htmlToAnswers);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error! -> " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Thoughts? Do I need to import a cert from Bluemix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a [known problem in the okhttp library](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2323). Are you using [Java SDK to use the IBM Watson](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) version `3.0.0-RC1`? If so, try with `2.10.0` as it has an older version of the `okhttp` library which may not suffer from this problem.